# Drop Down Navigation of Bootstrap is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing a issue with dropdown menu of twitter bootstrap, I need a help in resolving the issue. I am a very beginner to use bootstrap. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <a href="#" class="brand">brand</a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">connect
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your issue? you should state the issue or better yet, provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: your code is working fine on my system. whats the issue?

Comment: dropdown menu does not show up

Comment: Browser/operating system?

Comment: Can u see anything from the code like UL list without dropdown?

Comment: [link](http://postimg.org/image/zfia2ytpd/)

Comment: @RaviPal I cant see them

Comment: @TiesonT. Windows 7 Google Chrome

Comment: do you want your link to appear on hover or click?

Comment: @RaviPal I does not appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this between before closing head tag

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
```

then html part

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse"> 
        <div class="navbar-inner">  
        <div class="container">   
         <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
          <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
          <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
        </a>   
     <a href="pages/" class="brand"> Expense Manager</a>

      <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse">  
            <ul class="nav ">   
                <li class="dropdown ">  <a href="users" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Users <i class="caret"> </i> </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu mydropdown">   
                        <li> <a href="users/add" class="linkmain"> Add Users </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="users/" class="linkmain"> Manage Users </a> </li>
                    </ul>  
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown "><a href="users" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Users <i class="caret"> </i> </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu mydropdown">   
                        <li> <a href="users/add" class="linkmain"> Add Notes </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="users/" class="linkmain"> Manage Notes </a> </li>
                    </ul> 
                </li>
            </ul>  
            <ul class="nav pull-right">   
                <li class="active"> <a href="users/login"> Login to add your expense </a></li>
            </ul>   
     </div>
    </div> 
</div>
</div>
```

[Read tutorial here](http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2013/05/responsive-navigation-menu.html) and [See Live Demo here](http://aryan022.byethost13.com/myexpense/users/login)

Answer (score 0):

Attach `application.js` file to your js declarations in head... As far as you declared `bootstrap.min.js` and `bootstrap-dropdown.js`, `bootstrap.min.js` have js of all the element js of all the JavaScript entitles of twitter bootstrap, so need to attach `bootstrap-dropdown.js`...

Also use jquery latest version of code...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/application.js"></script>
```

Here's your working demo:-
http://jsfiddle.net/eGLMm/

Thanks...

Comment: Where is application.js i.e. where to download

Comment: i think if you have downloaded the bootstrap files it will be their... if you want to download then here:- http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/application.js

Comment: what browser are you using and version of it?

Comment: Google Chrome Version 27.0.1453.94 M (Latest)

Comment: I run Ubuntu in Virtual Box and made as the server and develop in it windows

Comment: ok, is this also not working http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

Comment: then my demo also runs fine check this:- http://i.imgur.com/yKVR6pC.jpg and your http://i.imgur.com/2PqDNJQ.jpg